# The following diagram is commutative. $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are injective. Prove that $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are bijective. Is my proof ok or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

> The following diagram is commutative.
> $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are injective.
> Prove that $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are bijective.

My proof:

> If $f_1$ is not injective, there exist $a,a'\in A_2$ such that $a\neq a'$ and $f_1(a)=f_1(a')$.
> Since $g_2=g_3\circ f_1$, $g_2(a)=g_3(f_1(a))=g_3(f_1(a'))=g_2(a')$.
> Since $g_2$ is injective, this is a contradiction.
> Similarly, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are also injective.
> Assume that there exists $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ such that $f_i$ is not surjective.
> Since $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are injective, $f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1$ is not surjective.
> So, there exists $a\in A_2$ such that $a\neq (f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1)(a')$ for any $a'\in A_2$.
> Since the diagram is commutative, $g_2(a)=(g_2\circ f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1)(a)=g_2((f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1)(a))$.
> Since $g_2$ is injective, $a=(f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1)(a)$.
> This is a contradiction.

Is my proof ok or not?

[image]

Comment: **1)** Injectivity is fine; more generally, when $X\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}Y\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}Z$, you have $(g\circ f\ \textrm{injective})\Rightarrow (f\ \textrm{injective})$, and $(g\circ f\ \textrm{surjective})\Rightarrow (g\ \textrm{surjective})$.
**2)** As for surjectivity you can simplify your proof by just saying that $g_2(a)=(g_2\circ f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1)(a)$ for all $a\in G_2$, which, by injectivity of $g_2$, implies that $f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1=\mathop{\rm Id}_{G_2}$, a _surjection_.
And then $f_3$ is surjective.

Comment: @jpboucheron Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: you're welcome.